# Establish the convergence and find the limit of $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, induction

I've just been introduced to the idea of series and I'm currently stuck on this problem:

Establish the convergence and find the limit of $a_n$ if
$$a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = \frac{2(2a_n + 1)}{a_n+3}, n \in \mathbb N$$

I figured that I'm suppose the prove that the series is increasing and bounded but I'm not sure how to prove either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all terms will be positive. A limit $l$ would have to satisfy $l = \frac{2(2l + 1)}{l+3}$ which has positive solution $l=2$. We can use that to find an easy solution by considering the series of terms $a_n - 2$ and proving this series tends to $0$.

We have $ a_{n+1}-2 = \frac{2}{a_n+3}(a_n - 2) $. Now $\frac{2}{3}>\frac{2}{a_n+3}>0$ and so $ |a_{n+1}-2|< \frac{2}{3}|a_n - 2| $. The required result is now obvious with $|a_2 - 2| $ less than  $\frac{2}{3}$, $|a_3 - 2| $ less than  $\frac{4}{9}$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Can you briefly explain what method/idea you used here $$ \frac{2}{3} > \frac{2}{_+3} > 0 $$ and how you were able to deduce this: $$ |_{+1}−2|< \frac{2}{3}|_−2|$$

Comment: Since $a_n$ is positive, the fraction $\frac{2}{a_n+3}$ has to be positive and less than $\frac{2}{3}$.  Then we combine this result with  $|a_{n+1}-2| = \frac{2}{a_n+3}|a_n - 2|$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$a_{n+1} = \frac{2(2a_n + 1)}{a_n+3} =4-\frac {10}{a_n+3}$$

Thus the sequence is increasing and bounded by $4$ thus it is convergent with a limit of $l$

The limit satisfies $$l=\frac {4l+2}{l+3}$$

Solving for $l$ and choosing the positive answer  results in $l=2$

Comment: How where you able to get $4 - \frac{10}{a_n + 3}$ from the given sequence? I'm still new to this topic so excuse my naiveness.

Comment: @BandSome Divide the numerator $4a_n+2$ by the denominator $a_n+3$ you get the quotient of $4$ and remainder of $-10$